# How to clear material ui autocomplete selected values on button click in react js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to clear material ui autocomplete selected values on click on reset button ? I am making the state as empty. But still its not happening.Can anyone suggest how to achieve this? Below my code.

```
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

    const providers = ['aaa', 'aaaaa', 'bbb', 'bbbbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];
    export default class PhysicianDetails extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {provider:''}
    }
    this.providerChange = this.providerChange.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);

    providerChange(value) {debugger;
        this.setState({ provider:value });
      }

    handleReset() {
    this.setState({provider:''});
    }
    render() {
     return(
    <div>
    <AutoComplete floatingLabelText='Providers' filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter} onUpdateInput={this.providerChange} dataSource={providers} />
    <RaisedButton label='reset' onClick={this.handleReset} />
    </div>
    )}
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4736#issuecomment-233788919

Comment: Thanks I fixed the issue.